# xslt template to match a substring value in an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76433198/808891), I've put together below XSLT that removes all empty elements with their parents except for some elements (`perm`) that cannot be removed regardless they are empty or not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(self::perm)][not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, I haven't been able to figure a way to not remove the elements that has in the `attr` the value `b` not empty. I was trying using `contain` but wasn't able to produce the expected result.

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1" attr="a='';b=''">
        <content>
            <notuse></notuse>
        </content>
        <desc>Item 1</desc>
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name" attr="a='';b=''">John</firstname>
            <lastname desc="Last" attr="a='';b=''"></lastname>
            <phone desc="phone" attr="a='';b='561-663-1254'"></phone>
        </details>
    </perm>    
    <perm desc="item_2" attr="a='';b=''"></perm>    
</item>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1" attr="a='';b=''">        
        <desc>Item 1</desc>
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name" attr="a='';b=''">John</firstname>            
            <phone desc="phone" attr="a='';b='561-663-1254'"></phone>
        </details>
    </perm>    
    <perm desc="item_2" attr="a='';b=''"></perm>    
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath, an attribute has a single string-value, with no recognition of the internal "sub-attributes" that your XML has.

In order to select only elements where the **b** property is empty (or doesn't exist at all), you can use the following predicate:

```
[not(substring-before(substring-after(@attr, "b=&apos;"), "&apos;"))]
```

However, this may fail if the format of the source XML changes even slightly - for example, if there are spaces surrounding the `=` character (e.g. `b = 'something'`). It also won't handle correctly an escaped apostrophe, if the format allows such thing.

Note also that this will require you to change the double quotes used for the entire match/select expression to single quotes.